# Is it possible in Zeppelin to keep running two paragraphs in parallel?

Tags: angularjs, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

What I want is basically for a Spark program to keep updating the display. The display paragraph would be written in angular. Now is there a way to keep running the Spark and Angular paragraphs in parallel in Zeppelin? If not, what are the alternatives for doing such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run 2 paragraph in parallel, one paragraph is angular, another paragraph is spark. But you can not run 2 spark paragraph in parallel.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. One in Spark and the other in Angular. The way I am doing is to use z.run from within my Spark code to call the paragraph of Angular. But is there a better way?

Comment: You can run the 2 paragraphs in parallel manually by clicking the run button if this is ok for you.